# Convert symbolic Cartesian coordinates to spherical

Tags: matlab, transformation, symbolic-math

Is there any way to do a **symbolic** transformation from Cartesian to spherical. I could do:

```
x = r * sin(theta)*cos(phi)
```

And so on, and then plug into an expression of x,y and z. Is there any easier command to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if [`cart2sph`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cart2sph.html) can do the conversion on symbolic objects, but its documentation has the mapping conveniently spelled out for you:

```
phi = atan2(y, x);
theta = atan2(z, sqrt(x .^ 2 + y .^ 2));
r = sqrt(x .^ 2 + y .^ 2 + z .^ 2);
```

I think you'll have to resort to this explicit transformation.